# Deferring tasks execution

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm playing with *Tasks* and I would like to defer my task's execution.

I've a sample method like this:

```cs
private async Task<bool> DoSomething(string name, int delayInSeconds)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Inside task named: {name}");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delayInSeconds));
    Debug.WriteLine($"Finishing task named: {name}");
    return true;
}
```

I would like to create few tasks first, then perform some job and after this run those tasks. As the line `Task<bool> myTask = DoSomething("Name", 4);` fires the task right away, I've figured something like this:

```cs
string[] taskNames = new string[2];

Task<Task<bool>>[] myTasks = new Task<Task<bool>>[2];
myTasks[0] =  new Task<Task<bool>>(async () => await DoSomething(taskNames[0], taskNames[0].Length));
myTasks[1] =  new Task<Task<bool>>(async () => await DoSomething(taskNames[1], taskNames[1].Length));

// I think I can declare it also like this, but this will create tasks later
//IEnumerable<Task<Task<bool>>> myTasks = taskNames.Select(x => new Task<Task<bool>>(async () => await DoSomething(x, x.Length)));

taskNames[0] = "First";
taskNames[1] = "Second";

Debug.WriteLine($"Tasks created");

var results = await Task.WhenAll(myTasks.Select(x => { x.Start(); return x.Unwrap(); }));
Debug.WriteLine($"Finishing: {results.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((a,b) => a + "," + b) }");
```

Can this be done different way, without wrapping task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `Task`-producing delegates to simplify things a bit:

```
string[] taskNames = new string[2];

Func<Task<bool>>[] myTasks = new Func<Task<bool>>[2];
myTasks[0] = new Func<Task<bool>>(async () => await DoSomething(taskNames[0], taskNames[0].Length));
myTasks[1] = new Func<Task<bool>>(() => DoSomething(taskNames[1], taskNames[1].Length)); // Shorter version, near-identical functionally.

// I think I can declare it also like this, but this will create tasks later
//IEnumerable<Task<Task<bool>>> myTasks = taskNames.Select(x => new Task<Task<bool>>(async () => await DoSomething(x, x.Length)));

taskNames[0] = "First";
taskNames[1] = "Second";

Debug.WriteLine($"Tasks created");

var results = await Task.WhenAll(myTasks.Select(x => x()));
Debug.WriteLine($"Finishing: {results.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b) }");
```

*Caveat*: `DoSomething` will execute synchronously up to the first `await` when you invoke those delegates, so the behaviour is similar, but not *exactly* identical.

Alternatively, your `IEnumerable`-based solution will work fine too. Just write an iterator method and `yield return` tasks as you start them.

Personally though I'd just do this:

```
string[] taskNames = new string[2];

taskNames[0] = "First";
taskNames[1] = "Second";

var results = await Task.WhenAll(taskNames.Select(n => DoSomething(n, n.Length)));
Debug.WriteLine($"Finishing: {results.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b) }");
```

Comment: Nice - I haven't thought about using *Func* to create tasks, what doesn't need further unwrapping. As it turned out with playing with all those samples, your solution has a big difference - all the tasks run on the same UI thread, they are running fine, because they are async.

Comment: That's right, that's exactly what my "caveat" part referred to. If you want to push things off to the thread pool ASAP, you could make your Func return `Task.Run(() => DoSomething(...))`, without having to unwrap the result - the choice is still there (although I must concede, it results in some pretty gross-looking syntax).

Answer (score 1):

You're not just "creating a `Task`" in your example. You're invoking a method, `DoSomething`, that *returns* a `Task`. Assuming these are `async` methods, the `Task` creation and starting takes place behind the scenes in compiler-generated code.

The solution to this problem is easy: Don't invoke the method until you're ready for the method to be running. Imagine how confusing the behavior you're asking for would be in any other context.

Comment: Generally I concur. Though I want to separate the task instantiation from its execution. Though it's just for purpose of learning some things.